# How to run an exe in a nested folder

Tags: c#

Hello I am really new at C# and I need to open an .exe from button click, the .exe is on a sub folder from the project, how can I open it?

I have something like Process.Start(@C:\users\myuser\desktop\repo\tools\exe.exe)

I need to share this project with others and I am not sure how can I open it without the full path.

Any help?

Comment: Using a dot `.` in your relative path means "current directory".  Granted be careful the current working directory doesn't get changed somehow.

Comment: As Zer0 pointed out you should use relative path.

Comment: You can use `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` which will return your app directory. From their, you go back or forward to the desired folder/subfolder.

Comment: You can get some standard folders (like the current user's *Documents* folder) using `GetFolderPath` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getfolderpath) and the `Environment.SpecialFolder` enum.  You can get the folder from which your EXE is running from `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.getexecutingassembly)

Comment: thank you I will give it a try and see if that works. Thank you So much

Comment: using appDomain totally work for me, thank you so much Kaj